# Populating datatable header values from json

Tags: jquery, json, datatable

I have json as shown below

```
{
    "aaData": [

        [
         "Name",
         "Description",
         "Date"
        ],
        [
            {
                "displayValue": "Home Page",
                "link": "http://somelink.com"
            },
            "London",
            "1983"
        ],
        [
            {
                "displayValue": "Backlog",
                "link": "http://BacklogApp.com"
            },
            "Paris",
            "1999"
        ]
    ]
}
```

Now in js, i am populating table using sAjaxSource as shown below

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#genericTable').dataTable( {
            "bProcessing": true,
            "sAjaxSource": "resources/json/" + key + ".json",
            "sPaginationType"   : "full_numbers",
            "bJQueryUI"         : true,
            "bRetrieve"         : true,
            "bPaginate"         : true,
            "bSort"             : true,
            "aaSorting"  : [[ 3, "desc" ]],
            "iDisplayLength"    : 50,
            "fnRowCallback": function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull ) {
                if(typeof aData[0] != 'string'){
                    $('td:eq(0)', nRow).html( '<a href="' + aData[0]['link'] +'" >'  +
                            aData[0]['displayValue'] + '</a>');
                }
            }
        }).columnFilter({ sPlaceHolder: "head:after",
            aoColumns: [ { type: "text" },
                         { type: "text" },
                         null
                       ]
        }); 
    });
```

I am able to populate data in the table with hard coded header names in jsp, but I want to populate Header names also from json. (Name, Description, Date). How can I do this.

Any idea???

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

It might be possible to perform the call before the datatables initialization so that you have the columns and data already. In my experience you have to define the columns in the "aoColumns" option.

here is an example of my column headings

```
"aoColumns" : [
                    { "sTitle" : "Status" },
                    { "sTitle" : "Name" },
                    { "sTitle" : "Url" },
                    { "sTitle" : "Page Views" },
                    { "sTitle" : "Leads" },
                    { "sTitle" : "Conv. Rate" },
                    { "sTitle" : "Actions" }
                ],
```

so mb write your json like this and then pass it into the intialization in an ajax callback

```
json = {
   "aoColumns": [ 
                   {"sTitle" : "Column Number 1"},
                   ....
                 ],
    "aaData": [ 
                 ....
                 .....
               ]
};

columns = json['aoColumns'];
data = json['aaData'];
```

Comment: "columns": [
                            {   
                                "sTitle" : "Title Name",
                            }
                  ]. 
sTitle did the trick, thanks